# Android dependencies versus libraries

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm building some Android apps using Android Studio. Adding dependencies/libraries is really easy by going to file -> project structure -> app -> Dependencies.

But this got me thinking, what exactly is the different between dependencies and libraries and how do they compare? (what's better)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Library is a dependency. Dependency means things that your app depends on. Dependency can be a module, library or a file.